# POI Excel Reader in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have issue reading subscript and Superscript using POI apache from Excel file (xls & xlsx). I googled everything but I am not getting any help. Currently I am using CELL_TYPE_STRING. I know this wont work.

Need solution for this.

Thanks

```
 public class ExcelSheetReader
{
public List readExcelFile(InputStream is)
{


List cellDataList = new ArrayList();
try
{

POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(is);

HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem);
HSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);


Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();

while (rowIterator.hasNext())
{
HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();

List cellTempList = new ArrayList();

while (iterator.hasNext())
{
HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell) iterator.next();
cellTempList.add(hssfCell);


hssfCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); 


}
cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

return cellDataList;
}


}
```

I have not made any effort in this code to get superscript or subscript. But I have tried this example

http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Reading-superscript-from-data-cell-td3414964.html#a3445867

But Still I am not able to read superscript or subscript

Comment: Would you be able to edit the answer to show what you have tried so far in your code (a minimal example would be preferable) and why it doesn't work?

Comment: @robjohncox I have updated code.. now waiting for your solution